# How much time should I budget to get to CDG airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, paris, cdg

I will be staying in the 11th arrondissement of Paris, and I will need to get to CDG for an 11:30 flight. I have two questions:

1. Does it make more sense to take public transport, or to take a taxi?
2. In each case, how much time should I allow to get there?

Comment: I'm guessing that is 11:30 in the morning? Also, what do you mean by "does it make sense"? I fear sense is, alas, subjective.

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes, in the morning. And "sense" here refers to cost:time ratio, mostly. In other words, if the train is slow/inefficient/unreliable, the expense of a taxi might be justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably the best way to get to the airport is by taking the RER B train since it isn't affected by traffic in the way that taxis can be (particularly at rush hour when you will be travelling).

The most convenient stop for the 11th arrondissement would be Châtelet - Les Halles which is a major hub. You could either take the Métro or a taxi to Châtelet - Les Halles.

The journey time from Châtelet - Les Halles is around 35 minutes on the express train (which skips some minor stations) and around 45 minutes on the normal train, but I would usually allow an hour for the journey. The ticket costs €10.30 one way.

The [RATP](https://www.ratp.fr/en/) website includes a good journey planner.

A taxi from the 11th arrondissement would probably take around an hour depending on traffic but will cost around 5 times the price.